# M.2 SSD is not recognized by BIOS

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, motherboard, bios

I am getting desperate with my brand new setup.

- MB: Gigabyte B450 AORUS M
- SSD: Samsung 970 evo 250Gb (M.2 under the GPU)
- HDD: Seagate Barracude 2T (SATA)

I got my PC built by seller. It came with windows on SSD, working fine, but with HDD not detected in Win nor in BIOS. Then I started messing arround, but nothing worked. The only way to see HDD was the situation, when I unplugged SSD. But when I plugged SSD back, it was not showing up. They just switch roles.

And now I can not see SSD no matter what I am doing.

BIOS is flashed and actual, I tried all kinds of restarts, setting changes, secure boot keys removing, battery unplugging, HDD unplugging and more...

But still I have no chance to see SSD. I installed windows on HDD to somehow try solve it from running instance, but still without results.

What do you think about it? Is there a chance that it's still about some kind of settings? I don't think I can damage ssd by a few gentle unmounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. This solution worked for me.

- Unplug every disk you have
- Eject motherboard battery and wait 30 sec.
- Put it back and connect only SSD
- Boot into BIOS and set Optimized default profile
- Save and exit - reboot

... and disk was visible.

**HDD must me plugged to SATA connector, not ASATA!** ASATA's share bandwidth with PCIex4 SSD NVm, so they are not working together and first connected has priority.